# cakephp: hasMany not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

device.php:

```
var $hasOne = array(        
        'Monitordevice' => array(
            'className' => 'Monitordevice',
            'foreignKey' => 'deviceId', // 'deviceId'
            'conditions' => '',     
        )
    ); 

    var $hasMany = array(   
        'CreativeSchedule' => array(
                    'className' => 'CreativeSchedule',
                    'foreignKey' => 'deviceId',
                    'conditions' => '',     

                    )

    );
```

---

creative_schedules.php

```
var $belongsTo = array(
        'Device' => array(
            'className' => 'Device',
            'foreignKey' => 'deviceId',
                    'conditions' => '',     
        )
    );
```

---

when I call this:

$all_devices=$this->Device->CreativeSchedule->find('all');

device table is not making any join with creative_schedules

instead I get 2 queries:

```
SELECT `Device`.`id`, ....FROM `devices` AS `Device` LEFT JOIN `monitordevices` AS `Monitordevice` ON (`Monitordevice`.`deviceId` = `Device`.`id`)
```

AND

```
SELECT `CreativeSchedule`.`id`, ....FROM `creative_schedules` AS `CreativeSchedule` WHERE `CreativeSchedule`.`deviceId` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: Are you setting the option `recursive` somewhere else in the code? Setting `recursive => -1` tells CakePHP not to join related models.

Comment: no, but my prob is solved, defined primary_key field for Device Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable).

In both of these classes, add:

```
var $actsAs = array( 'Containable' );
```

Then your find should look like:

```
$all_devices = $this->Device->CreativeSchedule->find('all', 'contain' => array('Device'));
```

As a side note, I'm not sure where you're putting the find(), and if that controller uses CreativeSchedule, but consider just $this->CreativeSchedule->find(...) if you can, as model chaining can lead to reduced performance, and it does not "link" the queries together through their associations. (Which I'm not sure if you were assuming or not.)

At worse case scenario, you could always put $this->loadModel('CreativeSchedule') at the top of the controller action if you would like.